# Do you receive the Mortgage value of a property every turn?

Tags: monopoly

My cousin mortgaged his property and he says every time it’s his turn he has to receive the mortgage amount on back of his card.

Eg: Illinois Ave Mortgage is $150 , he claims he gets $150 every time it’s his turn.

Comment: That is some creative banking. If that was the rule. Why would you ever develop your property. Mortgage all and break even in two turns.

Comment: The mortgage value of each property is typically a bit higher than the rent price with 1 house. If the game worked this way, mortgaging a property would effectively get you a 50% refund on the property purchase price, a free house (even with no monopoly), and someone to land on your property *every round*. Mortgaging a property should be a last resort, not a surefire winning strategy. Your cousin is nuts.

Comment: It's not just every time it's his turn. He can get $150 on everyone else's turn too. As [the rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/monins.pdf) say, "Unimproved properties can be mortgaged through the Bank at any time."

Comment: Were you playing this game on 1 April, by any chance?

Comment: Thanks. That’s what I told him and he claims he is supposed to get that much every time it’s his turn.

Comment: Does this work with houses in real life too?  

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's not how a mortgage works in Monopoly or real life!  A bank does not give you a perpetual income and ask you pay that amount plus 10% back once.  A Mortgage is a one-time loan based on the property value.  It is not a perpetual income.

The rules you need are all [here](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/00009.pdf). There is no reference anywhere that you get a mortgage value every turn.

> MORTGAGES: Unimproved properties can be mortgaged through the Bank at
>   any time. Before an improved property can be mortgaged, all the
>   buildings on all the properties of its color-group must be sold back
>   to the Bank at half price. The mortgage value is printed on each Title
>   Deed card.
>
> No rent can be collected on mortgaged properties or utilities, but
>   rent can be collected on unmortgaged properties in the same group. In
>   order to lift the mortgage, the owner must pay the Bank the amount of
>   the mortgage plus 10% interest. When all the properties of a
>   color-group are no longer mortgaged, the owner may begin to buy back
>   houses at full price.
>
> The player who mortgages property retains possession of it and no
>   other player may secure it by lifting the mortgage from the Bank.
>   However, the owner may sell this mortgaged property to another player
>   at any agreed price. If you are the new owner, you may lift the
>   mortgage at once if you wish by paying off the mortgage plus 10%
>   interest to the Bank. If the mortgage is not lifted at once, you must
>   pay the Bank 10% interest when you buy the property and if you lift
>   the mortgage later you must pay the Bank an additional 10% interest as
>   well as the amount of the mortgage.

Also think of the effect this would have on the game.  No one would ever lose.  Turn one I buy a property,  I then Mortgage it and I've an income every turn meaning I can't go bankrupt.  Every player would have all their properties mortgaged getting richer and richer so it would never end.